# Filter by multiple classes with radio buttons and jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to create a filter using radio buttons and jquery.

I have a list of items like the following:

```
<ul class="all-options">
    <li class="1 a">
        <img src="path/to/image"/>
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <h2>$1000</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="1 b">
        <img src="path/to/image"/>
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <h2>$1500</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="2 a">
        <img src="path/to/image"/>
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <h2>$1200</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="2 b">
        <img src="path/to/image"/>
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <h2>$1300</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to view just ONE item at a time, based on the user's selection from the following radio buttons:

```
<label>Numbers</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="1">1<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="2">2<br/>
<label>Letters</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="letter" value="a">a<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="letter" value="b">b
```

So, in order for one item to be shown, I know that BOTH classes would have to match the selection of the radio buttons. I'm very new to jquery though, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way, but it is the first thing that comes to my mind, and it works:

Assuming you have a filter button with `id="apply"`...

```
$("#apply").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $("[name='number']:checked").val();
    var letter = $("[name='letter']:checked").val();
    $("li").hide();
    $("li[class='" + number + " " + letter + "']").show();
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/6VXVV/)

---

**Better Version**

As the above will fail if your `li` elements have any other classes, here is an alternative approach using JQuery's `filter` method:

```
$("#apply").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $("[name='number']:checked").val();
    var letter = $("[name='letter']:checked").val();
    $("li").hide();
    $("li").filter(function (index) {
        return $(this).hasClass(number) && $(this).hasClass(letter);
    }).show();
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/6VXVV/1/)

---

You can apply this logic to any event, such as `change` for the radio buttons...

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
    var number = $("[name='number']:checked").val();
    var letter = $("[name='letter']:checked").val();
    //check if both radios have selected values before proceeding
    if (!number || !letter) return;
    $("li").hide();
    $("li").filter(function (index) {
        return $(this).hasClass(number) && $(this).hasClass(letter);
    }).show();
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/6VXVV/2/)

Of course, if any of your `number`s are `0` then they will not pass the value check as it stands.

Comment: Yeah, that works. But what if I want the filter to happen automatically on a 'change'  (when the user makes or changes their selection)?

Comment: @blicht454: I am sure you could have worked that out yourself, but I have updated to include this too. I am leaving now so cannot respond again... make sure you accept my answer if it solved your problem! ;-)

Comment: One last question if you have a minute: What if I wanted the first radio buttons in each category (letters & numbers) to be selected automatically? And have the filter reflect those selections, of course.

Comment: @blicht454: Sorry, wasn't around. If you haven't worked it out yet, you an set the radio buttons `checked` in html, and then fire the JQuery event after you set it up. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/6VXVV/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I just binded musefan code to an event listener (more precisely, the 'change' event), in order to have dynamic DOM interaction:

```
$(function () {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
    var number = $("[name='number']:checked").val();
    var letter = $("[name='letter']:checked").val();
    $("li").hide();
    $("li").filter(function (index) {
    return $(this).hasClass(number) && $(this).hasClass(letter);
    }).show();
  });
});
```

Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htCzD/).

Comment: Yes, this works really nicely. What if I wanted the first radio buttons in each category (letters & numbers) to be selected automatically? And have the filter reflect those selections, of course.

Comment: Then you'd want to wrap the filtering method in a function that you call on the first execution *and* on the change event, after defining some defaults. jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/htCzD/1/).